# Find who modified a TFS work item type definition

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem, tfs-process-template

A month ago I added a custom work item type to a TFS 2013 installed at one of our servers. This morning, the error "TF400917: The current configuration is not valid for this feature" showed when accessing the WORK tab using the web access. I used witadmin to download the custom WIT definition from the server and compared it with the definiton I uploaded a month ago to find that they were different (e.g. the DEFAULTREASON nodes where missing). After upload again the custom WIT definition, the error was solved.

How can I find who or what changed the WIT definition? I have looked at _oi/_diagnostics/activityLog and found some "Update" commands logged, but don't know if "Update" always implies a WIT definition change or how to find what definition was modified by each command.

Comment: You can do an update yourself then find out exactly what is logged in the activityLog

Comment: I don't think it is that clear, I tried to trace one the other day, and I found lots of "update" but I knew the people who do it, and roughly a time.

Comment: You can query the collection's database by running: select top 10 * from tbl_Command where Application='WorkItem Tracking' and Command='Update'
order by c.StartTime desc